# Getting different filter layout for grid in Angular application using Syncfusion UI

Tags: c#, .net, angular, web-development-server, ej2-syncfusion

I'm currently working on an Angular application with Syncfusion UI Kit for which a .NET Web API serves as the backend. I use VS Code for Angular and Visual Studio for API and have two profiles in Visual Studio namely QA and Prod.

The issue is when I connect to Prod Profile the filters for grid in the application are different than the filters when I connected to the QA profile in Visual Studio.

I'm confused and don't know how to debug this issue and find the solution.